# How to set value to multiple elements by class or tag selectors

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In JQuery I can set a value for `input` multiple elements at once using the class or tag selectors:

```
<form action="" id="mainForm">
    <input type="text" name="Phone" class="deftext" value="" > 
    <input type="text" name="Number" class="deftext" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="Name" class="deftext" value="" > 
    <input type="text" name="Lastname" class="deftext" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="Middlename" class="deftext" value="" > 
    <input type="text" name="Age" class="deftext" value="" >
    <input type="text" name="Email" class="deftext" value="" > 
    <input type="text" name="Occupation" class="deftext" value="" >
</form>
```

---

```
$('#mainForm .deftext').val("hello");
// OR
$('#mainForm input:text').val("");
```

Can I do the same in ExtJS 4 to modify the following code into single line?

```
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').down('[name=Phone]').setValue('');
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').down('[name=Number]').setValue('');
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').down('[name=Name]').setValue('');
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery code is not really readable, because when looking at the function you can't see that there are multiple fields affected. This is why ExtJS does not support such a syntax. Either you use

```
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').down('[name=Phone]').setValue('');
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').down('[name=Number]').setValue('');
```

or you use

```
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').getForm().setValues({
    Phone: '',
    Number: ''
});
```

Unlike your JQuery example, both of these are readable, because I don't have to know which classes have been applied to which fields.

If you want to reset all fields to the value that was set during the last [`form.loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord) operation, or the initial value if no `form.loadRecord` operation has been performed, use [`form.reset`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-reset):

```
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').getForm().reset();
```

Comment: The jQuery code seems plenty readable to me. Knowing that multiple *attributes* are affected (they're not fields) is a separate matter from whether the code is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if child components get something in common (xtype for example) you can do something like

```
Ext.getCmp('mainForm').query('textfield').each(function(component){component.setValue('')});
```

but no, you cant use component methods on array of components.

Comment: Well, at first glace no, `Ext.Array.each()` method just use `for` loop (source - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Array2.html#Ext-Array-method-each) and you have to call `setValue()` method for each component in array so I guess you have to loop through array anyway. As far as I know `for` loop is fastest way to loop through array in JS in general, so I guess its not "expensive" (I can bet that JQuery do something like that when you call `$('.deftext').val("hello");`).